# How do I remedy SELinux not allowing legit programs in use access to my system?

Tags: fedora, security, selinux, access-control

I have a system where some programs are getting access denied in SELinux when performing their duties. These programs are ClamAV, fail2ban and Logwatch.

I think I've managed to allow all the access for ClamAV (Clamscan), by following the directions in the SELinux Troubleshooter. I allowed fail2ban and Logwatch also in the troubleshooter but I suspect that they still are denied some access.

Here are the commands that allow a program:

```
grep fail2ban-client /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M mypol
```

and

```
semodule -i mypol.pp
```

Question:

How do I find out what access SELinux is denying these programs, the access they need on the system and how to remedy this?

Here is:
[ausearch -m avc](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=58D082BC056699E8&id=58D082BC056699E8!105)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes selinux denies the access to resources without logging. Check if the "do not audit" rules enabled or not. Use "semodule -B" or "-DB" to enable or temporary disable it.

Answer (score 0):

The location for SELinux logs are on there: logging is done in

```
/var/log/audit/audit.log
```

tailf that file and pipe it with grep to search for what you're looking for

Open /etc/selinux/targeted/booleans file using a text editor:

```
vi /etc/selinux/targeted/booleans
```

For example, in order to control Apache

Modify value for httpd_disable_trans as follows:
httpd_disable_trans=1

save and close the file. Type the following two commands:

```
# setsebool httpd_disable_trans 1
# /etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

if you want to do this on the X

Open a shell prompt

Type the command

```
system-config-securitylevel &
```

select SELinux tab > click on Disable SELinux protection for httpd daemon checkbox > Save the changes

```
# /etc/init.d/httpd r
```

restart for selinux to take the change

Comment: In /etc/selinux/targeted/ there is only a booleans file named "booleans.subs_dist"